# Writing code stage to determine if recipients are from the domain

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, blueprism

I need to write a piece of code in the Code Stage in Blue Prism. I am dealing with Outlook and my current object can send out emails in Outlook.

However, what I need to do now is to check if the email addresses in to/cc/bcc are from the same domain (eg. check if all recipients' email addresses end with "@abc.com"). My current piece of code is coded in C#. Does anyone have any idea on how this can be done?

Here is what I have currently:
I have a list of input parameters for fields like "to, from, cc, bcc, ..., abc_recipients_only". All the parameters are in string and the "abc_recipient_only" parameter is in a Boolean form.

The codes I have currently gives me an error saying "Compiler error at line 14: The name "Recipient" does not exist in the current context"".

```
    EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);
    
    to = to.Replace(',',';');
    cc = cc.Replace(',',';');
    bcc = bcc.Replace(',',';');
    
    foreach(var row in to.Split(';')){
        if (abc_recipients_only == true){
            if(Recipient.AddressEntry == "abc.com"){
                email.ToRecipients.Add(row.Trim());
            }
        }
        else{
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Trim())) continue;
            email.ToRecipients.Add(row.Trim());
        }
    }
    
    email.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MailItem.Recipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem.Recipients) property returns a [Recipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients) collection that represents all the recipients for the Outlook item. So, you can iterate over all items in the collection and check recipient's domains.

Use the Recipients (index) method, where index is the name or index number, to return a single Recipient object. The name can be a string that represents the display name, the alias, the full SMTP email address, or the mobile phone number of the recipient. A good practice is to use the SMTP email address for a mail message, and the mobile phone number for a mobile message.

The [Recipient.Address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.address) property returns a string representing the email address of the Recipient.

If you meet an exchange-like email address you can use the approach described in the [HowTo: Convert Exchange-based email address into SMTP email address](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/05/08/outlook-exchange-email-address-smtp/) article.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your company is using Exchange, loop through all recipients in the message (`MailItem.Recipients` collection) and check if each address type is `"EX"` - `Recipient.AddressEntry.Type == "EX"` or `Recipient.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3002001F") == "EX"`. The latter is more efficient.

Comment: Hmm I can't seem to get it to work as my recipient is in a string format. I am parsing a group of recipients as a string and looping through each of them. Do you know of a workaround for this?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - the Recipient object in OOM is definitely not a string. What is your code?

Comment: I have updated the codes into the question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: So you are **not** using the Outlook Object Model. Then you need to check each recipient's domain.

Comment: Yeah, does that mean I have to read through part of the string to do so? Or is there a feature that was created to handle situations like this?

Comment: I am not familiar with BluePrism, sorry